# Using karate.forEach and karate.set to extract index of value from json array

Tags: karate

I have the below json:

```
{
  "id": [
    "1A",
    "2B"
  ],
  "name": [
    "rs",
    "mk"
  ]
}
```

I want to extract the id value when name is 'rs' or 'mk'. There will be no duplication of `name` values and the size of `id` and `name` keys will always match.

So i have created the following scenario where:
- I iterate through the `name` array using forEach.
- Find if the value of `name` matches `rs` or `mk` and if it does, retrieve the index.
- Then use this index to find the retrieve the value from `id` key.

When I run this, the `name_rs_idx` and `name_mk_idx` are not being set and are blank.

```
Scenario: Using forEach and karate.set
    * def vals = { id: ['1A', '2B'], name: ['rs', 'mk'] }
    * def name_rs_idx = ''
    * def rsFun =
      """
        function(x, i) {
          if(x == 'rs') {
            karate.set(name_rs_idx, i);
          }
        }
      """
    * karate.forEach(vals.name, rsFun)
    * print 'RS Index - ' +  name_rs_idx
    * def name_rs_id = vals.id[name_rs_idx]
    * print 'RS id -' + name_rs_id

    * def name_mk_idx = ''
    * def mkFun =
    """
      function(x, i) {
        if(x == 'mk') {
          karate.set(name_mk_idx, i);
        }
      }
    """
    * karate.forEach(vals.name, mkFun)
    * print 'MK Index - ' + name_mk_idx
    * def name_mk_id = vals.id[name_mk_idx]
    * print 'MK id -' + name_mk_id
```

Maybe i am not using the forEach function correctly or logic is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are over-complicating things :) Here is my solution, take time to read and understand it, it will improve your Karate fundamentals ! To simplify things, we first combine the data into an array of `{ name: '', id: '' }` pairs. Then things become much easier.

```
* def vals = { id: ['1A', '2B'], name: ['rs', 'mk'] }
* def fun = function(x, i){ return { name: vals.name[i], id: vals.id[i] } }
* def pairs = karate.map(vals.name, fun)
* def fun = function(x){ return x.name == 'rs' || x.name == 'mk' }
* def filtered = karate.filter(pairs, fun)
```

Comment: I have a problem similar to the original poster, but in my case 'rs' and 'mk' have to be variables, I can't find any example of filter function with variables. What do you think I can do?

Comment: @MioMio ask a new question ?